# How to make ajax call in extjs and display the json value inside div?

Tags: extjs3

I am new in extjs. I need to know how to make ajax call in extjs and display the json values in inside div. I don't need to use grid..

Answer (score 4):

In ExtJS, you will have to use the Ext.Ajax class to make ajax calls to a remote server. Following is a typical code showing how to do it:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ajax_demo/sample.json',
    success: function(response, opts) {
       var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
       console.dir(obj);
    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {
       console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

In case of HTTP success (200 OK), the control will go inside the success callback and the first things that we have to do is decode the response.responseText which will give you the JSON response coming from the back-end data source.

Once you have code the JSON, you are free to format it and add it to any element (say to a div in your case). In case you want to format the JSON data nicely before adding, you may do that using Template/XTemplate.

Answer (score -1):

I have used something like this.

```
$.getJSON('somepathtoserver/somefile.php?callback?', variable,function(res){

});
```

In the somefile.php, I have a callback function that processes and return the value to the js function.

like this:

```
{
  echo $_GET['callback']. '(' . "{'someValue' : $calculatedVariable}" . ')';
}
```

This is tricky, but very useful when trying to ajax from one server to a different server, which is the reason I would use JSON here and not just a straight AJAX request.